# validating input radio with dynamic name field using jquery validation rule

Tags: jquery, laravel, validation

I am using multi step jquery form everything works perfectly I just want to validate every option. but the jquery validation not working because name field has dynamic value.
here is Radio button code

```
 @foreach ($item->answers as $list)
          
       @if ($item->option_type == 'radio')

            <div class="form-check hidden-check">
                 <input class="form-check-input radio" type="radio"
                    name="answers[{{ $item->id }}]"
                        id="questionnaire{{ $key . $list->id }}" value="{{ $list->id }}" >
             <label class="form-check-label" for="questionnaire{{ $key . $list->id }}">
                         <strong>o.</strong> {{ $list->answer }}
                                       </label>

                        
            </div>
         @endif
@endforeach
```

and here is jquery code for validation

```
 $(".next").click(function() {

            var form = $("#survey_form");
            form.validate({
                rules: {
                    "answers": {
                        required: true,

                    },
                },
                messages: {
                    "answers": {
                        required: "Required",
                    },

                },
                errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                    if (element.is(":radio")) {
                        error.appendTo(element.parents('.form-check'));
                    } else { // This is the default behavior 
                        error.insertAfter(element);
                    }
                }
            });
            if (form.valid() == true) {
                current_step = $(this).parent();
                next_step = $(this).parent().next();
                next_step.show();
                current_step.hide();
                setProgressBar(++current);
            }

        });
```

Comment: tried. not working

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Please first ***>>>[Search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+validate+dynamic+named+element+site%3Astackoverflow.com)<<<*** and  if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.